# Find files older than X days and output them by their size

Tags: files

I am trying to get the files older than a number of days and list them in descending order based on their size with all their information (size, full path etc - something similar that is provided by `ls`).

While I am able to locate files older with:

```
find . -mtime +10
```

I am not able to list of the desired information.

Comment: please add your distro and shell informations

Comment: @lese : AIX 6.1 ; while echo $SHELL --> /usr/bin/ksh

Comment: This sounds like a [XYProblem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676) ... do you really, as you ask, need ALL the files by size order? or are you (more likely) looking for "old" (>10 days) files big enough and just need, say, the 200 biggest to then decide which one of those you can delete to save some space?. In the latter case, and since you are on AIX with maybe no gnu tools, a combination of find (outputting all files >10 days) and awk (keeping top 200 biggest files in an array, then outputing it in order) will be your best bet

Answer (score 10):

Provided that your file paths **do not** contain newline characters:

```
find . -mtime +10 -printf "%s %n %m %u %g %t %p" \( \
  -type l -printf ' -> %l\n' -o -printf '\n' \) | sort -k1,1 -n
```

See [`find` manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html), section `Actions`.

- `%s`     File's size in bytes.
- `%n`     Number of [hard links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link) to file.
- `%m`     File's permission bits (in [octal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions#Numeric_notation)).
- `%u`     File's user name, or numeric [user ID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_identifier) if the user has no name.
- `%g`     File's group name, or numeric [group ID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_identifier) if the group has no name.
- `%t`     File's last modification time in the format returned by the C [`ctime`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ctime.3p.html) function.
- `%p`     File's name.
- `%l`     Object of [symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) (empty string if file is not a symbolic link).

BTW: Note that [POSIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780599/i-never-really-understood-what-is-posix) [`find`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1p.html) manual doesn't specify most of the above actions.

Comment: It says: find: 0652-017 -printf is not a valid option.

Comment: for me this works and seems a pretty clean solution +1

Comment: @user148335, you didn't mention what Linux distro you are running. It seems that you are limited to [POSIX find specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html), which is quite limited.

Comment: @patryk.beza I guess you was talking with user148335

Comment: AIX 6.1 ; while echo $SHELL --> /usr/bin/ksh

Comment: separetley this command works printf "%5d%4d\n" 1 21 321 4321 54321

Answer (score 4):

This command uses only POSIX features of `find` and of `ls`:

```
find . -type f -mtime +10 -exec ls -lS {} +
```

However, it *may* call `ls` more than once, if there are a *very large* number of files in the current directory (or subdirectories recursively) matching the `-mtime +10` primary.

If it calls `ls` more than once, of course, the sorting will only be done within each `ls` execution, not across multiple executions.

Still, for reasonable numbers of files, this is likely your best bet.

Comment: The updated version doesn't break with spaces in the name

Comment: If `ls` is being passed only one argument, there's little sorting it can do on it. With `+` instead of `;`, that would be better, but `ls` could still end up being called several times if there are many files.

Comment: This is the exact command I would have given, so I added the explanatory text I would have given to go with it.

Answer (score 3):

With `zsh`:

```
ls -ldrS -- **/*(m+10)
```

Or to avoid the double-sorting (by name by zsh and by size by ls):

```
ls -ldrS -- **/*(m+10oN) # disable zsh sorting
```

or (if your `ls` support `-U` for unsorted):

```
ls -ldU -- **/*(m+10oL) # disable ls sorting and have zsh sort by size
```

Add the `D` glob qualifier is you want to see hidden files as well.

Comment: Does this work when user and group names contain spaces?

Comment: @roaima, yes. Why would it not? It may break for E2BIG, which you can work around by using `zargs`.

Comment: Since you provided it, I suspected it would be fine, but I needed to ask :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do something similar to :

```
find . -type f -mtime +10 -print0 | sort -n -r -k1 | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' line; do
    #echo "$line"
    ls -lS "$line"    
done
```

notice the `-S` parameter of `ls` command :

> -S                         sort by file size

Comment: After dropping -d $'\0' because of the message : $\0: This is not an identifier I have managed to get the output but the files are not written descending based on their size

Comment: Will break when you encounter a directory under `/home/phphil`. Try `ls -ld ...`

Comment: @Roaima, what about using `find . -type f`instead ?

Comment: @lese I have changed the code but the command seems to throw twice each file from every subfolder. Ex.

Comment: `find ... -type f` would work, as would adding the `-d` flag to `ls`

Comment: @user148335 that's strange, are you sure? I think this still does not sort all files based on the size

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
find ./ -type f -mtime +10 -exec ls -ln {} \; | sort -r -k 5 -g
```

Comment: With the -n option, it's not a trouble because ls don't list username and groupname but uid and gid instead

Answer (score 0):

For an easier one-liner you could use the `find` option `-ls`. It appears in most cases the file size is at the seventh column of the listed information (so change `7` at the end of the command as appropriate if not):

```
find . -type f -mtime +10 -ls | sort -n -r -k7
```

Answer (score 0):

Another variation would be to use:

- find (to find the matching files)
- du (to show the filesize in KB)
- sort -n -r (to short in descending order)

Here's the command:

```
find . -type f -mtime +10 -exec du -k {} \; | sort -n -r
```